What is the origin of "Arsch offen haben"?
I would like to comprehend the origin of

Arsch offen haben

I just know it means verrückt sein, blöd sein, spinnen, unverschämt sein, but is there a way to guess what it means?
The origin of this idiom is not on DWDS, Redensartenindex, Duden or Wikipedia.

Erstaunlich ist, daß das Gegenteil "Ihm ist der Arsch zugeschnappt" in manchen Dialekten ein Synonym für "er ist gestorben" ist. Bedeutet das, dass "den Arsch offen haben" soviel wie "leben" heißt? (Das ist keine wirkliche Frage)

Interesting thing: I didn't know this meaning of this idiom. To me and all other speakers I have ever encountered using this phrase, it meant "have troubles (because of having done s.th. bad before)". Is this a regional difference? I am from Salzburg, Austria.

@rexkogitans For me, having lived in south Germany all my life (close to Stuttgart), "der hat doch den Arsch offen" always meant "he's doing something stupid/outrageous". I don't know the meaning of "having done something bad (and be in trouble because of that?)".

Also Interesting: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Arsch+offen&year_start=1500&year_end=2022&corpus=de&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=false

@rexkogitans: DWDS has an entry here, but offers just the meaning given by cp.

Any answer to this question will likely end up in speculation:
Control of your anal sphincter, however, is something humans acquire only once they have reasonable consciousness and are somewhat grown up - Not having that control might be a strong signal of a non-controlled, maybe even infant (or, on the other end: demented) mind. So it could roughly be translated to "be full of shit" (because that is the logical consequence of "Arsch offen") in English.
Quite a lot of German vulgar idioms seem to be including "Arsch", probably more than any other Wester European language. Mentioning of "Arsch" is, however, not always negative or abusive:

paßt wie Arsch auf Eimer
Arsch in der Hose haben
am Arsch der Welt wohnen
mit dem Arsch auf Grundeis gehen
.....


That's because German generally uses more fecal words in swearing as opposed to sexual words (Scheisse, verpiss dich - vs - fuck and fuck off). Of course over time and with influence if other languages, this is no longer as strict.

Technically if you have "den Arsch offen" you're no longer "full of shit", because it sips all over the place as the exhaust is no longer tightly sealed. It's rather used as "are you out of your mind", which would better match with the rest of what you said, that controlling these most basic functions or in that case the absence of that control is indicating diminished mental facilities.

@haxor That depends if you think of "full of shit" on the outside or on the inside.

Typically everyone is to some more or lesser degree full of shit unless they have recently taken a laxative. Therefore I'd side with tofro and would regard it with respect to the pants situation

Another (speculative!) interpretation: "Arsch offen" indicates anybody else can see the bare/nude ass because the "owner" of that ass forgot to pull up the trousers. This points into the same direction: loss of control or unacceptable social behavior.
